# Linux + what are the steps use the oldest kernel version in place of the current

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, grub

I have Linux red-hat 5 version
I want to reboot the machine with the previous kernel - 2.6.18-408.el5

so I set the default to 1

but before I will reboot the machine to startup with the older kernel version
please advice if I need to do some other steps additional?

```
 07:59:28 root@linux5Ver:~ # more /etc/grub.conf
 # grub.conf generated by anaconda
 #
 # Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
 # NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
 #          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
 #          root (hd0,0)
 #          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/rootvg/slash
 #          initrd /initrd-version.img
 #boot=/dev/cciss/c0d0
 default=1
 timeout=5
 #splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
 #hiddenmenu
 title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.18-409.el5)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-409.el5 ro root=/dev/rootvg/slash
    initrd /initrd-2.6.18-409.el5.img
    title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.18-408.el5)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-408.el5 ro root=/dev/rootvg/slash
    initrd /initrd-2.6.18-408.el5.img


   # uname -r
   2.6.18-409.el5
```

Comment: If you have the kernel 2.6.18-408 installed, you just need to modify your grub configuration which is located in /boot/grub/grub.conf (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/fr-FR/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-grub-configfile.html) and then reboot. Please take note that Grub start counting from zero when you define which kernel you want to boot.

Comment: so I need to edit the both files - /boot/grub/grub.conf and /etc/grub.conf and set the default on both files to 1?

Comment: I have no RHEL 5 in hand to test it, but normally you should edit /boot/grub/grub.conf for LEGACY Grub. Maybe /etc/grub.conf is a symlink to /boot/grub/grub.conf.

Comment: ok thx , dose default=1 actually escape on the first current kernel ?

Comment: If you use "default=1", it will point to  the kernel 2.6.18-408 from you're configuration. Hope this will works ;)